# Validation rule for applying to single and default scenario

Tags: validation, yii, yii2, yii-validation

I'm using Yii2 validator to validate my attributes. I have an validator rule, which should be fire on an specific scenario by using `$model->validate('run_special_validation');` and also at the default scenario when running `$model->validate();`

I know, that I can define the scenarios like this:

```
public function rules() {
    return [ 
        ['name', 'required', 'on' => 'run_special_validation'],
        ['email', 'required'],
    ];
}
```

What I need is to run the validation for `name` separately, for example by using `$model->validate('run_special_validation')`  and also together with all other validations by running `$model->validate()`.

//Edit: I know, there is an "ad hoc" validation available in Yii2, which maybe could be used. (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#ad-hoc-validation)  But is there a way to do that insight the model scope?

Comment: In which scenario you want to run special validation? On particular action or on particular condition? Ad hoc validation and scenario are different.

Comment: What about this: 

// scenario is set as a property
$model->scenario = "run_special_validation"
// scenario is set through configuration
$model = new User(['scenario' => "run_special_validation"]);